# Проблема при клонировании проекта с github репозитория

Tags: git, android-studio, github

Приветствую, ситуация такая:
Имеется репозиторий проекта на github.
В android studio 2.3.3 все успешно клонировалось, но в проекте использовался gradle третьей версии, пришлось удалить студию и установить Android studio 3.0.
В этой версии студии почему то клонирование проекта не удается, вываливается следующая ошибка

> Unable to read askpass response from 'C:\Users\Имя.AndroidStudioPreview3.0\system\tmp\intellij-git-askpass.bat'
>   failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
>   could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No error

Хотя в самой идее я задал для гитхаба логин и пароль, успешно протестированные.
Прошу вашей помощи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перенеси проект в такую папку, чтобы полный путь к проекту не содержал кириллицы.

Comment: А это баг или фича? С чем это связано? Гит прекрасно работает и папках с русскими названиями

Comment: ArcherGodson, ваш коммент помог мне разобраться. оказывается сама студия находилась в папке с кириллицей. После переноса студиии все заработало. огромное вам спасибо. mymedia, дело было в расположении самой IDE.

Comment: @mymedia боюсь, что баг и надо репортить разрабам. Идея, видимо, была в использовании спецсимволов, англоязычные кодеры частенько забывают, что юникод - не только псевдографика и всякие символы самолётиков..